# A GRE algebra question

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

[GRE Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muD5k.png)

Got this GRE question from my friend and we both stuck on it.

I think it's quite conceptual and we don't really need calculation.
It's still obvious that the slope between $P$ and $Q$ is $1$.

The answer is $B$, not sure why it's always true when the line $l$ tilted a little bit from $PQ$ then the slope is less than $1$.

Highly appreciated for any response.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It's preferred that you include images inline rather than linking to them, to increase the longevity of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to understand this question is to draw vertical lines through $P$ and $Q$, intersecting the given line $\ell$ at points $P' = (-2, y_p')$ and $Q' = (3, y_q')$, respectively.  We know the $x$-coordinates of $P'$ and $Q'$ are the same as the $x$-coordinates of $P$ and $Q$ because lines $PP'$ and $QQ'$ are vertical.

We also can observe from this diagram that $y_p' > 1$ and $y_q' < 6$.  Therefore, the slope of $\ell$ is $$m = \frac{y_q' - y_p'}{3-(-2)} = \frac{y_q' - y_p'}{5}.$$
$y_q' < 6$ implies $y_q' - y_p' < 6 - y_p'$, and $y_p' > 1$ implies $6 - y_p' < 6 - 1$.  Therefore,
$$m < \frac{6 - 1}{3+2} = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the slope of the line $PQ$ is $$\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2-x_1} = \frac{6-1}{3-(-2)}=\frac{5}{5} = 1.$$ Assuming the diagram is accurate, the slope of $l$ is smaller than that of $PQ$ (to see why, try shifting $l$ to the right so that $P$ lies on $l$, and note that $l$ crosses $y=6$ -- the $y$-coordinate of $Q$ -- later than $PQ$), hence (b) 'Quantity $B$ is greater' is the correct answer.